# How can I remove an input and clear data in that input?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to create a button that add more input and remove input and when it remove the input it also clear all the data inside that input but the problem is when I remove that input but the data still stay. How can I fix that ?

Here is my code base:

```
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(teamData.rules);

  useEffect(() => {
      setInputs(teamData.rules);
  }, [teamData]);

  // Add more input
  const addInputs = () => {
    setInputs([...inputs, { name: `rule-${inputs.length + 1}` }]);
  };

  // handle click event of the Remove button
  const handleRemoveClick = (index) => {
    const list = [...inputs];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setInputs(list);
  };

  {inputs.map((data, index) => (
    <div className="agreement-form-grid" key={index}>
      <button
        className="agreement-remove-button"
        onClick={() => handleRemoveClick(index)}
      >
        <Remove />
      </button>
      <input
        type="text"
        defaultValue={teamData.rules[index]}
        name={`rule_${index}`}
        placeholder={`Rule ${index + 1}`}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  ))}
  {inputs.length !== 4 && (
    <div className="team-agreement-add-rule">
      <button type="submit" onClick={addInputs}>
        <Add />
      </button>
    </div>
  )}
```

Update question add handleChange function:

```
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    // Update state
    setUpdateTeamData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  }
```

Comment: Can anyone help me with this ? Thank you so much

Comment: data mean what you have typed inside the removed input ryt? when you click the remove button of input at index 2 then what happens?

Comment: So happening is when I click remove input button it actually remove an input field but not the data inside it. When I click Save button the data is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define another function in your parent component to clear the data like below,

```
const clearInput = (dataName) => {
  setUpdateTeamData((prevState) => {
      delete prevState[dataName];
      return {
       ...prevState
      }
  });
}
```

In the child component, in the `onClick` of the remove button call this function as well

```
 <button
    className="agreement-remove-button"
    onClick={() => { handleRemoveClick(index); clearInput(`rule_${index}`)}}
  >
    <Remove />
 </button>
```

Before saving you can ignore empty inputs

Comment: ``this.setState`? is it like `setInput`?

Comment: how your `handleChange` looks like? this should behave similar to that and it should set empty string always.

Comment: Sorry for late reply @Amila I just updated my handleChange in the question. May you take a look?